# My np.vectorize'd function does not give the expected answer

Tags: python, numpy

I want to integrate some function over the unit disc.  To do that, I instead want to perform the integration over a larger square, and define the integrand to return zero when the point is outside the unit disc.

Anyway, that is why I want to define this kind of function:

```
import numpy as np

# f(x, y) = x**2 + y**2  inside the disc
def f(x, y):
    r2 = x**2 + y**2
    if r2 > 1:
        return 0
    else:
        return r2

fv = np.vectorize(f)
```

Now let's get some integration mesh:

```
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1,1,1001), np.linspace(-1,1,1001))
```

Take some arbitrary point inside the unit disc.  Before getting `vectorize`'d, my `f(x,y)` works as intended:

```
f2(xv[330,577], yv[330,577])
> 0.13931599999999994

xv[330,577]**2 + yv[330,577]**2 == f2(xv[330,577], yv[330,577])
> True
```

But the vectorized version `fv` does not give the same value.

```
fv(xv,yv)[330,577]
> 0
```

In fact, if you look at the array it returns, the whole thing is entirely messed up.  All but 14 entries are zero, inside or outside the unit disc.  Those 14 non-zero entries are exactly one.

A little help, please?

Comment: Did you read the `vectorize` docs?  See the stuff about determining the return dtype?  using `otypes`?

Comment: Also `vectorize` has a performance disclaimer

Comment: Notice that `f2()` returns a float, `fv()` returns an int.  That's a very significant difference.  Make sure you understand why before putting more effort into using `vectorize`.